# why DOM (Document Object Model) loads everything into main memory

Tags: c#, java, dom

Document Object Model(DOM) is used for representing `xml`,`html`

But am not able to understand why DOM loads everything into main memory.Is it used for enabling us to insert,delete objects in it or is there something else to it..

Also what are it's advantages that makes it's use so **wide**?

Comment: If you don't want to load the whole thing, use a SAX parser instead. The DOM API is basically random-access, so it loads all of the XML at once. SAX parsing is sequential and loads information as-needed in order w.r.t. the XML.

Comment: @Brian i know that..I want to know about DOM..

Comment: It's basically just what you said. DOM loads the entire thing because you can selectively access and modify the XML and jump between, say, nodes 1 and 4 in a child list. It's a sacrifice of memory for speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because to be able to implement a method such as

```
document.getElementsByTagName("foo");
```

you need to have parsed the document completely, and loaded the tree of nodes in memory. You could imaging reparsing the document at every method call, but it would be extremely inefficient.

What makes it so popular is that it's a standard API, supported by every language on earth, and which makes it relatively easy to navigate through the nodes and extract the information you want.

Comment: +1 Not only extract information, but also change the information.

Answer (score 1):

An XML document is essentially a tree structure. It is *convenient* to load the entire tree into memory at once. This is especially true with some XML schema, where certain nodes are dependent on other parts of the tree. That is the advantages of loading the document in its entirety. It also means operations such as applying an XSLT transform is simplified — and arguably more performant since the document is already in-memory. I/O is no longer required (and since most applications are I/O-bound rather than CPU-bound, this is a Good Thing.)

Disadvantages include:

- Speed. Until the entire document is loaded, you can't access it. Especially true for very large documents.
- Memory Usage. For large documents, the amount of memory consumed can be an issue, increasing  paging on the system.
- Validity. If the document is syntactically invalid or fails to validate against the schema, it is likely completely unusable, even if it's 95% valid. Depending on context, this might or might not be a problem. And for loading something like a random HTML document that likely contains lots of syntax/schema errors, this is an issue: a lot of error handling and assumptions built into that will be required to load the document correctly (for some definition of "correctly").

An event-driven parsing strategy like SAX is simpler. It requires, though, that the parse consumer keep track of state in a way that maintaining the full document structure in memory doesn't. Further, it is pretty much a single pass operation. If the consumer needs to backtrack through the document to achieve the desired effect...the consumer is going to need to maintain the stack necessary to do so. However, an event-driven parse uses much less memory, it may be processed as soon as parse events start getting raised and its much simpler (since it's passing a lot of the work off to the consumer).

I don't believe you can say one is *better* than the other; they're just different approaches. Depending on the context, one or the other approach might be better suited to the problem at hand.

One could argue that an XML parser that loads the entire document into memory is simply a general-purpose consumer of an event-driven SAX-style parser under the hood. Whether that's true or not, I don't know, but one could certainly do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

DOM is just that - object mode, a way to access something.

In most cases like in HTML loaded in a browser document is already loaded into memory and DOM just lets you access it in easily to understand way.

There is no explicit restriction on you when you implement DOM over your document. Implicit expectation is that iterating child nodes will be linear and going up/down in the tree will be constant time. Generally it is the easiest to have whole document loaded into memory to satisfy expectations but you don't have to.